# Adding hashes to filenames in Angular 2 apps for Production, not Dev with web pack

Tags: angular, hash, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I’m trying to add a hash to my app.js filenames for production builds only and am having trouble configuring webpack to do this **AND** still leave incremental builds with the webpack-dev-server functional.

For development, hashes break the incremental builder and the webpack-dev-server, so it's critical that the hash is only applied to the filename for production and deployment builds.

If I enable the hash, I have to stop, deploy and start my project in order for any changes to be picked up by the dev server.

I’ve tried moving the module.exports.output out into a conditional the same way that production and dev builds load separate plugins in webpack.config like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.output = {
        filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[hash:8].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
        publicPath: './build/',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash:8].map'
    }
} else {
    module.exports.output = {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
        publicPath: './build/',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
    }
```

However, this has no effect. Am I missing something, or is there a better way to do this?

Originally the output block was in the module.exports definition, and adding the [hash8] works:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash:8].chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
    publicPath: './build/',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash:8].map'
},
```

However any changes I made in the IDE during dev, while triggering a rebuild in VSCode aren’t reflected in the app running in the browser, so this is a configuration I can only set only for deployment builds.

I've also tried defining a variable and trying to code a condition in the naming block itself.

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

    output: {
        filename: `[name]${this.isDev ? '' : '.[hash:8]'}.js`,
        chunkFilename: `[name]${this.isDev ? '' : '.[hash:8]'}.chunk.js`,
        path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
        publicPath: './build/',
        sourceMapFilename: `[name]${this.isDev ? '' : '.[hash:8]'}.map`
    },
```

But this also doesn't work.